# @PrepareForTest, @RunWith and lambda expressions

Tags: java, unit-testing, lambda, mockito, powermock

Today I was debugging quite a huge test case that involved a lot of `whenNew` mocking.

Eventually it all boiled down to the fact that using `@PrepareForTest` and `@RunWith` annotations with `PowerMock` don't seem to execute lambda expressions inside the class that's being tested.

Here is a sample that shows the problem:

```
public class Solution {
    private int[] arr;

    void fillArray() {
        IntStream.range(0, arr.length).forEach(i -> arr[i] = i);
    }
}
```

And a test class:

```
@PrepareForTest(Solution.class)
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class SolutionTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        int[] arr = new int[5];
        Solution solutionMock = mock(Solution.class);
        Whitebox.setInternalState(solutionMock, "arr", arr);
        doCallRealMethod().when(solutionMock).fillArray();

        solutionMock.fillArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            assertEquals(i, arr[i]);
        }
}
```

In the preceding example lambda expression inside `fillArray` method never gets called and the test fails. Removing one of the annotations (or both) on the `SolutionTest` makes the test pass, but it not really a solution as I'd like to do some `whenNew` mocking.

So, ultimately my question is:

***Is there any solution or at least a viable workaround or fix to the problem stated above?***

Comment: Just as a side note: *Whitebox* is an "internal" class; you will notice that when updating to a recent version of Mockito (because that class is gone there). But alas, you wont be updating to a recent, more-fun-version of Mockito because PowerMock doesn't work with any *decent recent* version of Mockito. Totally off-topic: but when you want to spare yourself from such problems: try to get rid of PowerMock. Unless you are using it to test 3rd party code, there is **no** reason to use it. *Everything* that you need PowerMock for can be tested without it - when you fix your broken designs ;-)

Comment: Have you tried to use 'spy' instead of 'mock'?

Comment: One more question: which version PowerMock do you use? Mockito?

Answer (score 0):

This test passes with PowerMock 1.6.6 and Mockito 1.10.19. Make sure your versions are upgraded.